# Admob ads not working on specific package name

Tags: android, admob, android-manifest, ads, package-name

Issue is something like this I had a live app on play store since 1 year and it was working perfect with admob, suddenly it happened that ads stopped working/being visible on all app screens.I diagnosed and re uploaded a newer version on play store and nothing changed, still ads were not working then again i checked that when i change my application package name in the manifest and build app on device or emulator ads work perfect but when i use my actual package name it again disappear.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.
Ali

Comment: Did you contacted admob? i'm afraid if they have disabled ad service for your package due to some policy breach?

Comment: I did Babar.But they are not responding properly.

Comment: Well this is the biggest problem with google.

Comment: Did you receive a notification from Admob that ads had been disabled due to a policy violation?

Comment: William I double checked, I didn't receive any email from admob I have contacted them they have forward the issues to play store team lets see whats their response.Thanks.